# How to implement a custom default sorting using jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a table where the price column should be sorted by default(on page load) in descending order. It should also sort(asc or desc) upon clicking on this column.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/4uLsoxp0/).

## HTML

```
<div id="table_container">
    <table id="products">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

## JS

```
 var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
        "aaData": [
            [1, "car1", "<span class='hidden'><a class='imgLoading' href=''></a></span>$40.50"],
            [2, "car2", "<span class='hidden'><a class='imgLoading' href=''></a></span>$20.91"],
            [3, "car3", "<span class='hidden'><a class='imgLoading' href=''></a></span>$10.00"]
        ],
        "aaSorting":[[3, 'desc']],
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sWidth": "70%",
            "sClass": "center",
            "bSortable": false
        }, {
            "sWidth": "70%",
            "sClass": "center",
            "bSortable": false
        }, {
            "sWidth": "70%",
            "sClass": "center",
            "bSortable": true,
            "sType": "duration"
        }]

    });
```

Could anyone help me to implement this please?.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there:

```
var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
    "aaData": [
        [1, "car1", "$40.50"],
        [2, "car2", "$20.91"],
        [3, "car3", "$10.00"]
    ],
    "aaSorting": [
        [2, 'asc']
    ],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sWidth": "70%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": false,
        "sTitle": "id"
    }, {
        "sWidth": "20%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": false,
        "sTitle": "name"
    }, {
        "sWidth": "10%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": true,
        "sType": "currency",
        "sTitle": "price"
    }]
});
```

And include the currency plugin, alter your HTML to this:

```
<div id="table_container">
    <table id="products"></table>
</div>
```

The thing to remember is that the target is 0 based, therefor your target of 3 didn't exist, you needed to target 2 (id = 0, name = 1 & price = 2). Hope that helps.

Edited [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/4uLsoxp0/9/)

Basically you need to let DataTables do more leg work, and passing it in HTML isn't the best way to create cells, you can get it to do that for you:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "dom_currency-pre": function(a) {
        a = $(a).text();
        a = (a === "-") ? 0 : a.replace(/[^\d\-\.]/g, "");
        return parseFloat(a);
    },
    "dom_currency-asc": function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    },
    "dom_currency-desc": function(a, b) {
        return b - a;
    }
});
var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
    "aaData": [
        [1, "car1", "$40.50"],
        [2, "car2", "$20.91"],
        [3, "car3", "$10.00"]
    ],
    "aaSorting": [
        [2, 'desc']
    ],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sWidth": "70%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": false,
        "sTitle": "id"
    }, {
        "sWidth": "20%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": false,
        "sTitle": "name"
    }, {
        "sWidth": "10%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": true,
        "sType": "dom_currency",
        "sTitle": "price",
        "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
            return '<span><span class="hidden"><a class="imgLoading" href="#"></a></span>' + data + '</span>';
        }
    }]
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have edited my actual question. the column price will always have a html tag like "<span class='hidden'><a class='imgLoading' href=''></a></span>". Please consider this as well. Providing solution with a JSfiddle will be much appreciated.

Comment: Edited my answer, would be helpful if you didn't edit questions after they were answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should import currency plugin of datatable, and add type `currency` in your column 2 (remember begin in 0).

More information of currency plugin: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/currency

It's Working!!!

```
  var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
    "aaData": [
        [1, "car1", "<span class='hidden'><a class='imgLoading' href=''></a></span>$40.50"],
        [2, "car2", "<span class='hidden'><a class='imgLoading' href=''></a></span>$20.91"],
        [3, "car3", "<span class='hidden'><a class='imgLoading' href=''></a></span>$10.00"]
    ],
    "aaSorting":[[2, 'desc']],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sWidth": "70%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": false
    }, {
        "sWidth": "70%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": false
    }, {
        "sWidth": "70%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": true,
        "sType": "currency"
    }]

});
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/4uLsoxp0/2/